# Schwarz function with strictly positive Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

What is an example of a radial Schwarz function $f$ such that the Fourier transform of $f$ is strictly positive?

Answer (score 0):

How about the gaussian
$$
e^{-|x|^2}?
$$